# Is there a way to know the size of the whole UItableView?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

Basically the sum of all tableViewCell and headers I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you are looking for the contentSize:

```
 tableView.contentSize.height
```

should give you what you are seeking for

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
   tableView.contentSize.height
```